# How can i keep selected tab on page refresh in angular..?

Tags: angular, tabs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have two tabs, one is cluster list and template list. after I edited something in the template list, I wanted to come back to same selected template list. But its going to the cluster list. I tried with this line, But after updating template list its taking me to the cluster list. Appreciate your help on this.

[image: highlighted line i added]

[image: two tabs]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set data into route after updating form and coming back to list using [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History) . If your angular version >=7.2 You can save data in state.

Or else you can use below approach of saving data into localStorage/ sessionStorage

After saving/Updating data you can call this method before redirecting back to item listing page

```
 saveTabState(){
    const route = window.location.href;
    if(route.includes('templateform'))
    {
      localStorage.setItem('activeTabTemplate','true');
    }
    
  }
```

In item listing page

```
if(localStorage.getItem('activeTabTemplate')){
      this.activeTabTemplate = true;
      localStorage.removeItem('activeTabTemplate')
    }
```

In template

```
// for tab1:
[ngClass]="!activeTabTemplate ? 'active' : ''"

// tab2:
[ngClass]="activeTabTemplate ? 'active' : ''"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, your solutions are always prompt and helpful. it fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Input({ transform: numberAttribute })
```

```
selectedIndex: number | null
```

The index of the active tab.

#### Example

##### TS:

```
selectedTabIndex = Number(sessionStorage.getItem('selectedTabIndex') ?? '0');

handleTabChange(event: MatTabChangeEvent): void {
    // Save the current tab index to Storage
    sessionStorage.setItem('selectedTabIndex', event.index.toString());
}
```

##### HTML:

```html
<mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="selectedTabIndex" (selectedTabChange)="handleTabChange($event)">
  <mat-tab>
    TEXT 1
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab>
    TEXT 2
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).